# Only part of the audio player works

Tags: javascript, css, audio, audio-player

I have a HTML code:

```
<audio src="whale-music.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
<button class="oi oi-media-play b-play" id="play" onclick="play()"></button>
```

and the script:

```
<script>
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById('play').removeClass('oi-media-play')
        document.getElementById('play').addClass('oi-media-pause')
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
        document.getElementById('play').addClass('oi-media-play')
        document.getElementById('play').removeClass('oi-media-pause')
    }
}
```

It plays and pauses the song but it doesn't change classes, neither it returns to playing at point it was stopped (it plays from the beginning). What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

us this code

```
function play() {
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    document.getElementById('play').classList.remove('oi-media-play')
    document.getElementById('play').classList.add('oi-media-pause')
}else{
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0
    document.getElementById('play').classList.add('oi-media-play')
    document.getElementById('play').classList.remove('oi-media-pause')
}}
```

the "removeClass" and "addClass" is a jquery syntax

Comment: Oh my god that works! The only problem now is how do I check that the media stopped playing so I can change the icon back to "oi-media-play"?

Answer (score 0):

if you use native code:

```
 document.getElementById('play').classList.remove('oi-media-play');
 document.getElementById('play').classList.add('oi-media-pause');
```

or Jquery:

```
$('#play').removeClass('oi-media-play');
```

Comment: Oh my god that works! The only problem now is how do I check that the media stopped playing so I can change the icon back to "oi-media-play"?

Comment: you can addEventListener to the video tag: onpause, onplaying